# Change AWS Credentials Dynamically at Run time c#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I need to send Emails using AWS SES and need to change the credentials based on the client request. Is there a way to change credentials at runtime in C# .Net?

Comment: There is. Look at the AWS SES SDK's client for constructors that accept credentials: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SimpleEmailV2/TSimpleEmailServiceV2Client.html

Comment: @MartinCostello Thank you so much, This worked.